# Excel Code keeps crashing but no Error in code, Application-Definded or object defined error

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

I am writing a userform in which i have a listbox, when a user selects and item in the listbox it goes to row range in the datasheet and deletes it from the table (list object called data). The problem is i Keep getting a runtime error for the higlighted line of code. I have read online but am not sure how to solve the problem, the error says application-defined or object defined error.

I have tried to change the way i reference the table , but it still doesn't work

```
Private Sub Delete_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim tabl As ListObject
Set tabl = ShNewDAt.ListObjects("Data")

 For i = 0 To tabl.ListRows.Count
    If ListBoxDisplay.Selected(i) Then
        tabl.ListRows(i).Delete         ' THIS LINE GIVES AN ERROR
    End If
 Next i

End Sub
```

The commented line gives the error

Comment: A `ListObject` can't have a `.ListRows(0)` row.

Comment: Also, may I offer that you loop backwards when deleting rows ? try `For i= tabl.ListRows.Count to 1 Step -1`

Comment: I tried it same error as before

Comment: You never define `ShNewDAt`

Comment: @tigeravatar I'm assuming that's the *code name* of a worksheet module in `ThisWorkbook`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object collections *want* to be iterated with a `For Each` loop. `ListObject.ListRows` is one such object collection.

The loop has a very high chance of throwing an *index out of bounds* error: you're iterating based on `ListRows.Count`, but the main driver is `ListBoxDisplay`.

By using a `For Each` loop, you avoid the problems caused by modifying the collection as you iterate it, because the collection won't get re-evaluated at each iteration. On the other hand, with a `For` loop you are deleting rows at `i`, but doing that will offset the rows underneath, and result in rows being deleted ...that shouldn't have been. But that's ignoring that object collections start at index 1, not 0: if `ListBoxDisplay.Selected(0)` is true, expect error 1004 at `.ListRows(i)`.

One way to fix this is to separate the concerns of *knowing what rows to delete* and *deleting rows that need to be deleted*:

```
Dim toDelete As Collection
Set toDelete = New Collection

Dim currentRow As ListRow
For Each currentRow In table.ListRows
    If ListBoxDisplay.Selected(currentRow.Index - 1) Then
        toDelete.Add currentRow
    End If
Next

For Each currentRow In toDelete
    currentRow.Delete
Next
```